# Shared libraries can't be found inside a screen session

Tags: gnu-screen, java

I'm running a jetty-based Maven web application on Red Hat Linux. When I run it using the normal command, `mvn jetty:run`, it runs fine.

However, when I try to run this command under a *screen* session or *nohup* command, it has trouble finding shared libraries.

These shared libraries are *.so* files stored in a folder named *lib*. I add this folder to my Java library path in *~/.bash_profile*.

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/group/lib"
```

I wanted to know why my Jetty webapp doesn't work when I run it with *screen* or *nohup*. I thought that *screen* at least inherits the environment variables from the parent process.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

[`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) (and even [`nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup): it is not necessarily a built-in) can start a [subshell](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html).  If your shell initialization sets `PATH`, for instance, and you've sourced some script to get the Java environment set up, then starting a shell like this will break things as described.

Comment: I see. Could I fix it by setting the same environment variable in .screenrc?

Comment: Offhand I don't recall that `.screenrc` is useful for that purpose. Or you could rerun the initialization that you did to setup Java...